# Burninate tag: applied-theory

Tags: discussion, tags

This is sort of a goofy-sounding tag. I'm not sure what the guy who thought this one up had in mind, but I think that "applications" or "applied-science" would be a better wording.

Comment: What is this "burninate" word? Something from Harry Potter?

Comment: @DaveClarke [The true meaning of burninate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120640/the-true-meaning-of-burninate)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[applied-theory](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/applied-theory), [applications](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/applications), [applied-science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/applied-science) make no sense. A tag notes a sub-domain, a topic, a class of questions that people will be particularly interested in or particularly not interested in. Distinguishing between theory and applications (as opposed to particular theoretic or applied domains) is useless.

Let's get rid of [applied-theory](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/applied-theory).

Comment: Yeah, this was sort of my feeling, perhaps, as well. It's almost like a meta tag... not useful in isolation, only modifying others. Really evil.

Answer (score 0):

I think I created it. The rationale was probably the wish to tag applied questions, that is not purely theoretic (as in TCS, but also as in purely academic) ones, so that people not interested in theory can easily grab what they want.

I still think it can be a useful tag. We have not used it consistently, though, and should start doing so if we decide to keep it.

The name can certainly be discussed. [applications](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/applications) is bad, imho, as it is ambiguous for people that do not have a (formal) CS background and do not bother to read FAQ and tag excerpts; given the amount of mistagging we have, this seems to be real danger (even if maybe not a problem). [applied-science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/applied-science) sounds as if it included more than computer science, but this is not a problem in the context of this site. It also fits above motivation better.

Tl;dr: Keep the tag, but rename to [applied-science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/applied-science).

Comment: I'd like the applied-science tag better... of course, there was no intention to offend anyone who made any of these tags (I think Kaveh might have been a little offended at some of my comically rude phrasing). Naturally, I'm only suggesting this to see what others think... if the community wants the tags like they are, I won't lose any sleep ;D

Comment: I disagree. [tag:applied] (or [tag:applied-science] or whatever) is far too vast. We might have tags for [tag:physics], [tag:biology] and so on, for applications to other disciplines. Why not go the other way round and tag theory questions [tag:theory]? The tag makes no sense.

Comment: the tag made sense on cstheory where we wanted to make sure practical applications of theory are also on-topic and research-level restriction is more relaxed for them, but I don't think it makes much sense on [cs.se].